# What status code to return for data that doesnt fit the server's data constraints?

Tags: rest, http, http-status-code-400

When somebody sends me a field that has too many/invalid characters, or an email thats already taken, or numbers for a first name, I have always sent back a 400 with a list of field validation errors.

Is this the right thing to do? reading through all the 400s [here](https://httpstatuses.com/) is starting to make me question the right way to say "I understand the data, I understand the content-type and your headers, but I can't put this in my database".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [422](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422) which means the general layout of the request is correct but its content could not be processed.

I usually take the 422 in a scenario liked described. Otherwise, I would respond with [400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400).